# How to solve 'The column label 'Avg_Threat_Score' is not unique.'? issue in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

When running the code I am facing following error. 
error - The column label 'Avg_Threat_Score' is not unique.

I was creating a pivot table and wanted to sort the value from high to low.

```
pt = df.pivot_table(index = 'User Name',values = ['Threat Score', 'Score'], 
        aggfunc = {
                   'Threat Score': np.mean,
                   'Score' :[np.mean, lambda x: len(x.dropna())]
                  }, 
        margins = False) 

new_col =['User Name Count', 'AVG_TH_Score', 'Avg_Threat_Score']
pt.columns = [new_col]
#befor this code is working, after that now working 
df = df.reindex(pt.sort_values
                    (by = 'Avg_Threat_Score',ascending=False).index)
```

need to sort the values high low for column 'Avg_Threat_Score'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pt = df.pivot_table(index = 'User Name', values = ['Threat Score', 'Score','Source IP'] ,  
                    aggfunc = {"Source IP" : 'count',
                              'Threat Score':np.mean,
                               'Score': np.mean})

pt = pt.sort_values('Threat Score', ascending = False) 
new_cols = ['Avg_Score', 'Count', 'Avg_ThreatScore']
pt.columns = new_cols
```

Answer (score 5):

You need pass new columns names by list, not by nested list, because pandas create `MultiIndex` with one level.

```
new_col =['User Name Count', 'AVG_TH_Score', 'Avg_Threat_Score']
pt.columns = [new_col]
```

Is same like:

```
pt.columns = [['User Name Count', 'AVG_TH_Score', 'Avg_Threat_Score']]
```

> ValueError: The column label 'Avg_Threat_Score' is not unique.
>   For a multi-index, the label must be a tuple with elements corresponding to each level.

So use:

```
pt.columns = ['User Name Count', 'AVG_TH_Score', 'Avg_Threat_Score']
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'User Name':list('ababaa'),
         'Threat Score':[4,5,4,np.nan,5,4],
         'Score':[np.nan,8,9,4,2,np.nan],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0]})

pt = (df.pivot_table(index = 'User Name',values = ['Threat Score', 'Score'], 
        aggfunc = {
                   'Threat Score': np.mean,
                   'Score' :[np.mean, lambda x: len(x.dropna())]
                  }, 
        margins = False))

pt.columns = ['User Name Count', 'AVG_TH_Score', 'Avg_Threat_Score']
print (pt)
           User Name Count  AVG_TH_Score  Avg_Threat_Score
User Name                                                 
a                      2.0           5.5              4.25
b                      2.0           6.0              5.00
```

And then for sorting by ordering from `Avg_Threat_Score` use ordered [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) for column `User Name`, so last `sort_values` working:

```
names = pt.sort_values(by = 'Avg_Threat_Score',ascending=False).index
print (names)
#Index(['b', 'a'], dtype='object', name='User Name')

df['User Name'] = pd.CategoricalIndex(df['User Name'], categories=names, ordered=True)
df = df.sort_values('User Name')
```

---

```
print (df)
  User Name  Threat Score  Score  D
1         b           5.0    8.0  3
3         b           NaN    4.0  7
0         a           4.0    NaN  1
2         a           4.0    9.0  5
4         a           5.0    2.0  1
5         a           4.0    NaN  0
```

Comment: @MDSAQUIBNASIRKHAN - What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: User Name            55630 non-null object, Threat Score         55630 non-null int64, Score                55630 non-null int64

Comment: @MDSAQUIBNASIRKHAN - Error is also with my sample data ?

Comment: @MDSAQUIBNASIRKHAN - Because tested in pandas 0.24.2 and working nice. What is your pandas version?

Comment: getting error on - names = pt.sort_values(by = 'Avg_Threat_Score',ascending=False).index

Index(['b', 'a'], dtype = 'object', name='User Name'), Error - name 'Index' is not defined

Comment: @MDSAQUIBNASIRKHAN - It is only output of print, remove or comment it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194000/discussion-between-md-saquib-nasir-khan-and-jezrael).